# How to get last updated Adsgroups from Facebook

Tags: facebook-ads-api

How do you only retrieve the "last" updated Adgroups from Facebook via the Ads API? I.e. only Adgroups updated after time t?

If this doesn't work, is there a way to only retrieve active ones?

Answer (score 0):

The Ads API uses [ETags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/etags-reference/), so you can extract the `ETag` HTTP header from the adgroup request, and use it the next time you retrieve your adgroups. If you place the code into a `If-None-Match` header, then the API will only send you the adgroups that have changed since the ETag was generated.

Comment: This works for some of the scenarios. Thank you! However, this still requires batch requests to be made to all of the adgroups. I was hoping there is a may to just get the updated ones without having to loop through them all.